# RabbitMq : Theoretical Scalability of a single Publisher

Tags: rabbitmq

**Setup**

We have one publisher (channel) and cca 1000 consumers (classic queues, no persistence, no HA). There is massive publish rate and all queues get all messages. Consumers keep up (at least the total size of ready messages is way below the watermark).

**Goal**

We want to keep latency under control.

**Question**

Can this be scaled indefinitely (by adding more nodes and CPUs) if publish rate and/or number of consumers is increasing?
Let's assume RABBITMQ_DISTRIBUTION_BUFFER_SIZE is big enough and it is within a on-premise single network and bandwidth is way below the theoretical maximum.

Comment: Have you considered the stream queue ?

Comment: @GabrieleSantomaggio: thanks a lot. We did consider streams. But :
1) we would need to change the api for the clients which we do not control. (Now there is a queue per client and we do the bindings for them dependent on the permissions).
2) we expect that disk must be involved and the latency would go worse (at least in lower percentiles)